# C++ Array Reinitialization using Braces

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there any way to reinitialize an array in C++ using braces?

For example, I want to be able to do something like the following, but it gives an error.

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
...
arr[] = {8, 23, 19, 91, 9, 30, 1, 3, 1, 32};
```

Want to do it just like how it's done in Python

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
...
arr = [9, 5, 4]
```

Comment: Have you considered using `std::vector` instead of arrays?

Comment: I forgot to mention. I strictly want to use default C++ arrays. No vectors

Comment: Default C++ arrays do not have the (Python-like) behavior you are asking for.  If you used `std::vector` you'd have that behavior, albeit with slightly different syntax.

Comment: You could maybe do something with `std::copy`, `memcpy`, or a hand-rolled loop. But the big problem is that your two arrays are different sizes. That's not easy to deal with unless you make `arr` big enough for the largest and keep a separate variable with the length.